# Firebase Integration using WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I integrated the push notification system with Firebase in my project and it's working well. Few clarficiation

Steps to follow the integration of Firebase

1. Created the json file from firebase console and added in my project ( google-services.json )
2. Dependency compile lib added in my build.gradel ( root as well as inside of app)
3. AndroidManifest.xml added the following server.

   ```
   <service
   android:name="com.myfirebase.myfirebasemsgservice"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="true">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
   </intent-filter>
   </service>
   ```
4. Inside of the "myfirebasemsgservice" added the following line and proceeding and working well.

   ```
   public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage fcmMessage)
   {
   Log.d(TAG, "From: " + fcmMessage.getFrom());

    if (fcmMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
     Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + fcmMessage.getData());
       Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + fcmMessage.getData().toString());
   ```
5. I checked and got an notification if sending from firebase console as well as ARC (Advanced REST CLIENT). I tried Notification Payload and Data Payload both are working well.

**My clarification and how we need to integrate in firebase same like below code. How we did previously means?. Any idea and how we need to integrate like this?.**

1. AndroidManifest.xml - added previously.

   ```
                     <receiver
              android:name="com.mygcm.gcmbroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
               <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
             <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
             </intent-filter>
                 </receiver>

               <service android:name="com.mygcm.gcmIntentService" />
   ```
2. gcmbroadcastReceiver added the below code.

   ```
         public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver 
      {
      @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
       GCMIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        }
        }
   ```
3. gcmIntentService added the below code.

   ```
              public class gcmIntentService extends IntentService {

               @Override
                   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
                 {
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                 GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
                String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

   try 
   {
       if (!extras.isEmpty()) 
       {
           if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) 
           {
               Log.d("LogData",intent.getStringExtra(Constants.PAYLOAD));
           } 
           else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) 
           {
               Log.d("LogData",intent.getStringExtra(Constants.PAYLOAD));
           } 
           else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) 
           {   
               Log.d("LogData",intent.getStringExtra(Constants.PAYLOAD));
           }
       }
   } 
   catch(Exception ignored)
   {
       ExceptionTrack exe_track=ExceptionTrack.getInstance();
   }
   finally {
       GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: have you managed to to find a solution ?
from what i know 
`The FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver is a WakefulBroadcastReceiver that receives FirebaseInstanceId and FirebaseMessaging events and delivers them to the class that you derive from FirebaseInstanceIdService.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <service
        android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".fcm.FireBaseInstanceID_Service">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

App Gradle

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Project Gradle
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Log.e("token_id", FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());

Answer (score 1):

```
     import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;
import com.loyalty.preferences.LoyaltySharedpreference;


public class FireBaseInstanceID_Service extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        //Getting registration token
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        //Displaying token on logcat
          }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {

    }


}
```

Comment: Refreshtoken is not an issues and i did like this only. But my question like how can i do the same integration by using WakefulBroadcastReceiver?...

Comment: Is it get the notification when the app is removed from the Latest App used. In my case it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
    package com.example.fcm;


import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;




public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo2)
                .setContentTitle(" Notification")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());



    }
}
```

Comment: This is what i did presently and working well. But my question like how can i do the same integration by using WakefulBroadcastReceiver?...

Answer (score 0):

Please check in other device. Because some device not allowing apps to run in background by changing settings . So Firebase services are disabled.

I faced this problem thats why i shared with you .